# How to work with arguments in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, eclipse

new guy here.  I am trying to learn C++ using Mac OS X and am having serious issues getting a debugger to work in either Eclipse or Netbeans (cannot get gdb for some crazy reason) so have decided to try my hand in Xcode.  I have a simple sort program written but don't know how to get the output file to populate.  Here's what I've done so far:

1. Created a list of names and saved it in the Sort folder as Names.txt.
2. Went into the "edit scheme" tab in Xcode and added the two arguments Names.txt and Output.txt.
3. Ran the program with no errors or issues but Output.txt does not get created.
4. In Xcode, I pulled Names.txt in with the "add file to sort" and also created a blank Output.txt file and saved it in the Sort folder.  I then pulled Output.txt into Xcode as well.
5. Ran the program and still have a blank Output.txt file.

Here is the code as written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Constants
#define BUFFER_SIZE 50
#define ARRAY_SIZE 20

// Global variables
int numElements = 0;

//function prototypes
void sort(string elements[]);  // sort an array of strings in ascending order

void swap(string& s1, string& s2); // swap s1 and s2

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    string listOfNames[ARRAY_SIZE];

    string inputFileName;
    string outputFileName;
    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream  outputFile;

    if(argc != 3) {
        cout << "Error: Please enter input and output files ";
        cout << "as command line arguments !" << endl;
    }
    else {
        inputFileName = argv[1];
        outputFileName = argv[2];
        inputFile.open(inputFileName.c_str());
        outputFile.open(outputFileName.c_str());

        // Read names from input file and store into array
        while(!inputFile.eof() && numElements < (ARRAY_SIZE - 1)) {
            inputFile.getline(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            string p = string(buffer);
            listOfNames[numElements] = p;
            numElements++;
        }
        // Sort elements in array
        sort(listOfNames);
        // Print elements in array to output file
        for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            outputFile << listOfNames[i] << endl;
        }
        inputFile.close();
        outputFile.close();
    }

    cout << "Sorting done!!!" << endl;

    return 0;
}// end main


// perform bubble sort
// sort names in ascending order
void sort(string elements[]) {
    bool change = true;

    while(change) {
        change = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < (numElements - 1); i++) {
            if (elements[i] > elements[i + 1]) {
                swap(elements[i], elements[i+1]);
            change = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

// swapping 2 string
void swap(string& s1, string& s2) {
    string temp = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = temp;
}
```

I am confident the code is correct as it works in Eclipse...I just don't know how to get the Xcode to produce the output file.

Comment: How do you know `Output.txt` doesn't get created?  Where do you specify the file path?

Comment: I am adding Output.txt as an argument in the edit scheme of Sort.  It should build in the same folder as Sort.cpp shouldn't it?  Please let me know if I'm wrong but I can't find any Output.txt on my computer other than the copy I made myself, which remains blank.

Comment: If you're using a recent mac os, then instead of using `gdb`, you should be using `lldb`. You could use a cout of `getcwd` to determine where your app is running from and where you should find the file.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is almost certainly that you're not looking in the program's working directory. That's where 'Output.txt' is being created, and IIRC by default it's in a directory Xcode creates for the project in Xcode's Application Support area inside your ~/Library folder.

You can set the working directory in the scheme, I believe. You can also use the Organizer to open up the folder Xcode creates for the project.

Note that this affects both your Output.txt and your Names.txt; `std::ifstream` won't open a file just because you've added it to the Xcode project. You either need to use an absolute path or put the file in the working directory.

> It should build in the same folder as Sort.cpp

Nope. It will be created in the 'current working directory' that your program runs with. Different IDEs will set that to be different places. If you run your program from the Terminal.app then it will be whatever location you are in when you run the program.

> I can't find any Output.txt on my computer

Since the default location is somewhere inside ~/Library directory searches in the Finder will only find the file if you check the option 'search system folders', or whatever it's called. Better to just look up what Xcode sets the current working directory to in your scheme or in Xcode's organizer.